# jQuery - Reading from xml file generated by program and rendering on a page - Ampersands break script

Tags: jquery, xml

If I have text like

Title: SAFE AND SOUND
Artist: CAPITAL CITIES

It works fine, but as soon as the program introduces text like

Title: SAFE & SOUND
artist: CAPITAL CITIES

the script will not render it. If I try escaping the string, it turns the spaces into %20 but still fails to do anything with the & and fails to render the thing at all.

Note: We cannot change how the program renders the xml file, and what it renders is technically not valid XML (no declaration, or character encoding, and the line items are not escaped) We have to work with what we are given.

here is part of the script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    function getSong() {
       var song= $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/dalet/nowplaying2.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            async : false,
            cache : false,
        }).responseXML;

   $(song).find('Current').each(function(){

     var title = $(this).find("titleName").text();
     var artist = $(this).find("artistName").text();

     $("#nowsongtitle").html(title);
     $("#nowsongartist").html(artist);

  });
   }
setInterval(function() {
getSong();
}, 5000);
});
```

Here is what the XML looks like coming out of the program (Dalet 5.1)

```
<BroadcastMonitor>
<updated>2013-11-30T13:53:25</updated>
<stationName>Unknown</stationName>
<Current>
    <startTime>2013-11-30T13:53:25</startTime>
    <titleId>8839</titleId>
    <itemCode></itemCode>
    <itemReference></itemReference>
    <titleName>Safe And Sound</titleName>
    <artistName>Capital Cities</artistName>
    <albumName>Hitzone 67 (CD2)</albumName>
</Current>
<Next>
    <startTime>2013-11-30T13:56:36</startTime>
    <itemId>1000000627:7514</itemId>
    <titleId>8827</titleId>
    <itemCode></itemCode>
    <itemReference></itemReference>
    <titleName>L'amour</titleName>
    <artistName>Karim Ouellet</artistName>
    <albumName>Fox</albumName>
</Next>
</BroadcastMonitor>
```

Comment: ampersand are not allowed in XML, except for in certain tags, like the title tag if I remember correctly, so if it's breaking something, whatever it's breaking isn't working properly

Comment: I would just cheat and do this -> http://jsfiddle.net/vjvFc/

Comment: Not sure i understand your last part. Dalet the program that generates the file is limited in what control over the output we have. Changing the software (dalet) is out of the question

Comment: And I've dealt with API's like this before, and it's not uncommon at all, and I usually solve it with a little string replacement, replacing the $ with something else that is not very likely to occur in the string, and then replacing back before outputting the text. see my above example.

Comment: simple solution is use another server file to retrieve, wrap and clean the xml and use that file as ajax url

Comment: @adeneo I've tried your jsfiddle example, and I am getting a DOM error: 

Uncaught TypeError: Object #<XMLHttpRequest> has no method 'done'

Comment: In what version of jQuery ?

Comment: Whatever ships with drupal 7.. jQuery 1.4.4 I think

Comment: Just updated to 1.7 and there is a new error: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Document> has no method 'replace'

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your xml document isn't properly encoded. You either need to escape the ampersand:

```
<titleName>Safe &amp; Sound</titleName>
```

or place the contents of that tag within a CDATA section:

```
<titleName><![CDATA[Safe & Sound]]></titleName>
```

If you're unable to change the xml document itself, you may have to do a string replacement in the xml returned from the server, before using the jQuery xml decoder to parse it. If you look at the [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) documentation, there's a section that describes customizing the response decoder.

Comment: Again, we have no control over how Dalet outputs the XML. as far as we can tell, it's not customizable. it is exactly how you see it.